# Solutions for $ \frac{dy}{dx}=y $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Al-right, this may be a very basic question but I'm confused about this. We all know that one differential equation can only have one solution. Consider:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=y $$

The solution is:

$$ y= e^x = c(1 + x +x^2/2 + ... ) = c( 1 + \int 1\times dx + \int \int 1 \times dx^2  + ...$$

where c is a constant. Wouldn't this work as a solution as well?

$$ y = c(... -1/x^2 + 1/x + \log(x) + (x \log(x) - x) + ... = c \times (...+ \frac{d^2 (1/x)}{dx^2} + \frac{d (1/x)}{dx} + (1/x) + \int 1/x \times dx + ... )$$

Can someone tell me why the seond solution is wrong?

Comment: How did you derive that second "solution"?

Comment: I guessed it. One can verify it by:
$$ y = c \times (...+ \frac{d^2 (1/x)}{dx^2} + \frac{d (1/x)}{dx} + (1/x) + \int 1/x \times dx + ... )$$
Then
$$ dy/dx = c \times (...+ \frac{d^2 (1/x)}{dx^2} + \frac{d (1/x)}{dx} + (1/x) + \int 1/x \times dx + ... ) = y $$

Comment: @Hakim, Both solutions are sums of all derivatives and antiderivatives of some function $f$. In the case of $e^x$, $f=1$. In the other case OP took $f=1/x$.

Comment: My guess is that the infinite sum of your solution diverges.

Comment: So in essence I could possibly take $$ y = ... f''(x) + f'(x) + f(x) + \int f(x) dx + ... $$ will always diverge unless $ f(x) = c e^x $ ?

Comment: $\forall x<0; \log(x)\notin \Bbb R$  where as $\exp(x)\in \Bbb R$...Maybe you try it with $\cdots + x^{1/2}+ \cdots $, ah that won't work either... BTW: +1

Comment: * $$ y = c e^x $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `solution' you mean solution to the initial value problem (IVP)
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y,\qquad y(0) =c,\qquad x\in\ \mathbb{R}.$$

It follows from the [Picard–Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) theorem there exists a solution to the above IVP and that solution is *unique*.
So if $y(x) = ce^x$ is a solution, then it is the only one.
For the second 'solution', $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}y $ is not even defined!